# How to auto capitalize the first character in a string?

Tags: string, indexing, ascii, capitalization, charat

I want to auto capitalize the first character in a string like if I enter "john" through keyboard, the data saved in the variable would be "John". So how can i add 32 to the first character of the string to capitalize it? please show me the way. 
Thanks.

Comment: What tool or language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You should write it on your own such as

```
Console.WriteLine(CapitalizeFirst("cihan"));

private string CapitalizeFirst(string s)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
   {
       return string.Empty;
   }
   return char.ToUpper(s[0]) + s.Substring(1);
}
```

Then the output will be Cihan

Answer (score 0):

`$("input").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.ctrlKey || event.altKey){
        return; 
    }else{
        $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase()); 
        str =  $(this).val();
        str = str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
        $(this).val(str);
    }
});`